# Excluding specific row elements from row-wise function evaluation for 3D array [r]

Tags: arrays, r, 3d, apply

I would like to apply a custom function to each row of a 3d array, excluding a specific value stored in the vector nul. For the ith row of the array (either layer), I would like to exclude from evaluation all values in that row matching ith value in the vector nul.

```
  mat <- rep(cbind(c(1,3,0,1,4),c(0,4,1,2,1), c(2,3,0,4,0), c(1,0,4,2,0), c(0,2,3,0,1)),2)
  arr <- array(mat, dim=c(5,5,2))
  nul <- c(1,3,5,8,4)
```

I have tried many different things, but the closest I have come is:

```
 x1 <- apply(arr,c(1,3), function(x)myfun(x[x!=(nul)]))
```

However, this results in the exclusion of row elements in arr which match corresponding row elements in nul for each row in nul.

"myfun" is a summation for sake of simplicity, though in reality this will be something more complicated:

```
> nul
[1] 1 3 5 8 4
> arr
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    2    1    0
[2,]    3    4    3    0    2
[3,]    0    1    0    4    3
[4,]    1    2    4    2    0
[5,]    4    1    0    0    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    2    1    0
[2,]    3    4    3    0    2
[3,]    0    1    0    4    3
[4,]    1    2    4    2    0
[5,]    4    1    0    0    1

> x1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    3
[2,]   12   12
[3,]    8    8
[4,]    8    8
[5,]    6    6
```

As you can see, only the "1" at position [1,1,1] is excluded, instead of each matching value in that row. In addition, the function excludes "1" in each row, instead of just the first.

The desired output is:

```
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    6    6
[3,]    8    8
[4,]    8    8
[5,]    2    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the *which* function instead

```
res <- cbind(rep(0,5), rep(0,5))          #is the result matrix
count <- 1                            #is the dimension count of the array
while (count <= dim(arr)[3]){
    for (i in 1:nrow(arr[,,count])){
        res[i,count] <- sum(arr[i,c(which(arr[i,,count] != nul[i])), count])
    }
    count <- count + 1
}
```

However i don't understand the ultimate output part.